# EF Core Cascading Delete requires Include, ThenInclude despite Mappings

Tags: entity-framework-core, cascade, cascading-deletes, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have three classes with relationships defined as

Definition (has many) -> (references back to) Section (has many) -> (references back to) Fields

A Definition has many Sections, and Sections belong to a single Definition. Similarly for Sections and Fields.

```
public class Definition
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; } = new List<Section>();
}
```

and

```
public class Section
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long DefinitionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Definition Definition { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; } = new List<Field>();

    public virtual ICollection<Section_Product> Products { get; } = new List<Section_Product>();
}
```

Section has a *DefinitionId* foreign key defined in the DB as well. Ignore the Fields part if you wish. What I want to do is to be able to cascade delete Section when I delete Definition.

To be able to do that, I linked them to one another using

```
builder.Entity<Definition>()
            .HasMany(d => d.Sections)
            .WithOne(s => s.Definition)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.DefinitionId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

When I use the following method to delete

```
var loading = context.Definition
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Loading");

if (loading != null) context.Remove(loading);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Section__Definit__2E1BDC42". The conflict occurred in database "EFCoreDB", table "dbo.Section", column 'DefinitionId'

However, if I do

```
var loading = context.Definition
            .Include(x => x.Sections).ThenInclude(s => s.Fields)
            .Include(x => x.Sections).ThenInclude(s => s.Products)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Loading");

if (loading != null) context.Remove(loading);
context.SaveChanges();
```

it works without a problem.

I am not sure why all the Include() and ThenInclude() business is necessary.

What is going on? Why do the Cascade Delete not recognize Foreign Key dependency and required delete option?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you try by removing `virtual` from relations

Comment: @viveknuna: I tried it both ways. Still the same result.

Comment: Apparently the database doesn't match the mappings. In particular, the FK constraint from `Section` to `Definition` has no `ON DELETE CASCADE`. From the name of the constraint I assume you are not using EF Core migrations to maintain the database schema. In such case you should update the database manually to match the mappings.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Is there no way to avoid the On Delete Cascade entry in the DB? Let's say the DB is shared and I do not want to impose anything on other programs. I figured that placing the .OnDelete(...) clause would lead to the EF understanding it is required.